# Unable to use delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I'm new to objective c and trying to grasp the delegate methology and usage. Currently i have Alertview class, and i need it to make a another class to call function of its. I'v managed to do the same with with appdelegate class. But can't do it with my own class.

```
                TableViewController *newControll = (TableViewController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
                [newControll openSettings];
```

That's how I'm trying to access my method. Compilator see's this method in newControll, yet calling this gets unrecognizet selector.

Basicaly i need to call a function of which was already created earlier, from another class. I'm sorry if this is a simple solution, but i just can't grasp delegate and objective-c quite well yet.

Maybe not everyone get's what I need to do, so i'll try to explain once more.

I have object `TableViewController`. From this object inside I'm calling class `AlertView` to display some alert message. And accordingly to user interaction in alert dialogs (password is ok, password isn't) I need to call method `openSettings` in my `TableViewController` or not call. So how to do this?

Comment: I dont know that you want, but compilator say rigth things.. ) at first - are you sure [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate isnt nil? second - [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate may not have any selector openSettings.

Comment: it will help you can post some code!!

Comment: Which part would you like to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `TableViewController` is not your appdelegate class, you should use the object of `TableViewController` to use the method `openSettings`.

It should be something like,

```
TableViewController *newControll = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
```

Assuming that you are moving to a new `alertView`. In your `AlertView.h` file add,

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) TableViewController *tableViewController;
```

And while creating the new `alertView` object,

```
AlertView *alertView = [[AlertView alloc] init];
//some code..
alertView.tableViewController = self;
```

Now in your `AlertView` class, call it as,

```
[self.tableViewController openSettings];
```

Usage of appdelegate is not the way to do it.

If you need some tutorials on iOS, [check raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials).

Comment: Tried this way, but it doesn't get it done properly, because i need to make a call to an exact object which was created earlier, not create a new one and make a call.

Comment: Where is the newControll created? In which class? and where are you trying to call this method? Anyways updated my answer.

Comment: I'v updated my question, please take a look, maybe it will be more clear what I am trying to do

Comment: @Datenshi, Is alertview a separate class? If yes, check my answer.

Comment: Yes, it worked just as I wished to. I'm sorry if i didn't understood your answer in first place. Thank you for your help !